# JSF2 Primefaces 3.4 can i make ajax call to backing bean method without server side API means pure client side code submission

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to submit some value to server on some client side event which i am not able to get with server side events.

(1) Primefaces.ab(formName,methodName,parameter)

Wanted to do something like above mentioned code. Actually i am trying to save Rows per page event in primefaces but following event:

do not returns current rows per page that's why i am getting value with help of Jquery and css class of Row per page template and i need to submit that value to server side method.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, [the `<p:remoteCommand>` component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf) is intented. Basically, it allows you to let PrimeFaces generate a JS function reference with the desired function name which in turn invokes the desired backing bean action method.

E.g.:

```
<h:form>
    <p:remoteCommand name="functionName" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

Which is then to be invoked as:

```
<script>
    functionName();
</script>
```

You can use a JS object as argument in order to pass request parameters:

```
<script>
    functionName({ paramName: "paramValue" });
</script>
```

Which is then available in action method as:

```
String paramName = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("paramName"); // Contains "paramValue".
```

Comment: Thanks allot for quick answer

Comment: You're welcome. No, it shouldn't be an array. Just a JS object. If you want to specify multiple params, just specify multiple object properties like so `{ name1: "value1", name2: "value2", name3: "value3" }`.

Comment: the right way to call is 
        ([{name:'name1', value:'value1'}, {name:'name2', value:'value2'}])

Comment: @Mic: no, see the previous comment.